# Can't click the element due to popup

Tags: python, exception, selenium, popup, handle

Try to click the element but always have an UnexpectedAlertPresentException.Adding UnexpectedAlertPresentException to the code do not chage anything because element was not clicked and popup was not appeard.I thought maybe its due to popup dont have much time to appear but its didnt help too.
Event try to accept all popup via capabilities...

```
cap = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
cap["UnexpectedAlertPresentException"] = "accept"
fox = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap)

fox.find_element_by_link_text("My Account").click()
try:
    WebDriverWait(fox, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                               'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' +
                               'confirmation popup to appear.')
    fox.switch_to.alert().accept()

    print "alert accepted"
except TimeoutException:
    print "no alert"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try..

```
try {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
} catch (Exception e) {
    //exception handling
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenium 2 switchin alert is changed. Change your command to `fox.switchTo().alert().accept();`

Comment: I try this and its didnt change anything , still got UnexpectedAlertPresentException.

Comment: put `import time; time.sleep(2);` for debuggin before popup to check that it opens

Comment: Another problem occurred AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'switchTo'

Comment: maybe your driver version support previous one: `fox.switch_to.alert().accept() `

Comment: when fox.switch_to.alert().accept() UnexpectedAlertPresentException occurred.